# Populate MPAndroidChart Bar chart with SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, mpandroidchart

I have a MPAndroidChart that I want to use to display the results of a SQL Query giving the sum of my income column and grouping it by income_category. Another user on here got me closer to getting it to work, but I am receiving a null object reference error when I do the BarChart.setData. Debug shows the query works, so I can't figure out why it is null. Below is the code in the BudgetDbHelper:

```
public ArrayList<BarEntry> getBarEntries() {
    String income_sum_column = "income_sum";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[]{"SUM(income) AS " + income_sum_column,"income_category"};
    Cursor csr = db.query("transactions",columns,null,null,"income_category",null,null);
    ArrayList<BarEntry> rv = new ArrayList<>();
    while(csr.moveToNext()) {
        rv.add(new BarEntry(
                csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex("income_category")),
                csr.getFloat(csr.getColumnIndex(income_sum_column))
        ));
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
```

And here is the code for the CYIncomeChartActivity:

```
public class CYIncomeChartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

    // Database helper object //
    private BudgetDbHelper mDbHelper;

    BarChart barChart;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cy_income_chart);

        mDbHelper = new BudgetDbHelper(this);
        sqLiteDatabase = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = mDbHelper.getBarEntries();

        BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries,"Income By Income Category");
        barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        BarData barData = new BarData(barDataSet);
        barData.setBarWidth(0.9f);

        barChart.setData(barData);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `barChart` is null, because you never set it to anything. You need something like

```
barChart = findViewById(R.id.my_chart);
```

in there before you can call

```
barChart.setData(barData);
```

Comment: I feel like such an idiot for forgetting something so easy! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Tyler v can you help me with this,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51618305/how-to-change-bar-color-in-mpandroidcharts-based-on-some-individual-value-stored